# Iterate over inner field in struct

Tags: rust

I want to implement a `Iterator` for a `struct` so easily loop over an inner field but I can't get it to work.

The return from `IterWrapper::next()` is faulty.

Maybe there is an easier solution to accomplish this.

```rust
struct Wrapper {
    pub items: Vec<String>
}

struct IterWrapper<'a> {
    inner: &'a std::slice::Iter<'a, String>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for IterWrapper<'a> {
    type Item = &'a String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner.next();
    }
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> IterWrapper<'a> {
        IterWrapper {
            inner: &self.items.iter(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    
    let w = Wrapper {
        items: vec![String::from("test1"), String::from("test2")]
    };

    for item in w.iter() {
        println!("{}", item);
    }

}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:27
   |
13 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |        ----               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `std::option::Option`, found `()`
   |        |
   |        implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
14 |         self.inner.next();
   |                          - help: consider removing this semicolon
   |
   = note:   expected enum `std::option::Option<&std::string::String>`
           found unit type `()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple changes that you have to make:

```rust
struct Wrapper {
    pub items: Vec<String>
}

struct IterWrapper<'a> {
    // this needs to own the iterator, not a reference to it
    // in order to avoid returning a borrowed value
    inner: std::slice::Iter<'a, String>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for IterWrapper<'a> {
    type Item = &'a String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // no semicolon here so the result is implicitly returned
        // your old error happened because the semicolon causes the value to not be returned
        self.inner.next()
    }
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> IterWrapper<'a> {
        IterWrapper {
            // give the iterator, not the reference to it
            inner: self.items.iter(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    
    let w = Wrapper {
        items: vec![String::from("test1"), String::from("test2")]
    };

    for item in w.iter() {
        println!("{}", item);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification the `;` issue I should have seen